# Measuring correlation between random variables when they are not normally distributed?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, finance

I want to perform some analysis on portfolio that consists of stocks. In particular, I want to know the relationship between the stocks during the downmarket.

The problem complicating this analysis is that stocks are not normally distributed. If they are normally distributed, then I could just use their pearson correlation coefficient. Since they are not, I think I have to use some sort of skewness, kurtosis, etc. measures.

How would I be performing the analysis if the underlying stocks are not normally distributed?

Comment: The meaning of the correlation is the same regardless of the distribution of the variables.  Neither kurtosis nor skewness measure any aspect of a relationship between variables, because they are univariate statistics.

Comment: @whuber So how would you perform some sort of portfolio diversification effect during the downmarket if they are not normally distributed?

Comment: I am not very familiar with portfolio optimisation --- but am I correct in saying that you were assuming the returns of the stocks jointly follow a multivariate normal distribution?

Comment: @XiuboZhang Yes

Comment: @JunJang In that case maybe copula-based methods could help? e.g.  https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jbankfin.2013.02.036

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try log the response to aim for normality, trying different log base values. Alternatively you could use models that do not require normal distributions. GAMM's, quasi-poisson-GLMM.

Usually stock portfolio price distribution looks naturally poisson.

You will have to account for auto-correlation with ARMA combinations inside a quasi-poisson-GLMM or an identity matrix inside a GAMM.